# Project Euler 454

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand this problems core, but I seem to be missing something simple.

[image]

I made such test script, to understand, how the numbers are truly generated:

```
$limit = 15;

$result = array();
$count = 0;
for ( $x=1; $x<$limit; $x++ ) {
  for ( $y=1; $y<=$limit; $y++ ) {
    for ( $n=1; $n<=$limit; $n++ ) {
      if ( ( ( 1/$x + 1/$y ) == 1/$n ) && ( $x < $y ) )
        $count ++;
        $result[$count]['x'] = $x;
        $result[$count]['y'] = $y;
        $result[$count]['n'] = $n;
    }
  }
}
echo count( $result );
```

For F(15) I get 4, but for F(1000) I only get 877 ( instead the 1069 that is mentioned in the problem itself ).

Where is my mistake in the logic of my script?

*EDIT: Working script*

```
$count = 0;
$result = array();
for ( $x=2; $x<$limit; $x++ ) {
  for ( $y=2; $y<=$limit; $y++ ) {
    $n = ($x*$y)/($x+$y);
    if ( is_int( $n ) && ( $x<$y ) ) {
      $count++;
      $result[$count]['x'] = $x;
      $result[$count]['y'] = $y;
      $result[$count]['n'] = $n;
    }
  }
}
echo count( $result );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that `$n` shouldn't be inferior to `$limit`, which is the case in your code :).

I wouldn't put `n` into a loop. I'd rather set it like `n = x*y/(x+y)`, which is the case actualy !

```
$limit = 15;

$result = array();
$count = 0;
for ( $x=1; $x<$limit; $x++ ) {
  for ( $y=1; $y<=$limit; $y++ ) {
      $n = ($x*$y)/($x+$y);
      $condition = ($x*$y)%($x+$y);
      if ( ( $condition == 0 && ( $x < $y ) && ( $y <= $limit ) )
        $count ++;
        $result[$count]['x'] = $x;
        $result[$count]['y'] = $y;
        $result[$count]['n'] = $n;
  }
}
echo count( $result );
```

Comment: Thank you, mistake understood and corrected. Now to think of an algorithm instead of brute force :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simplify your loops a bit. Since `x<y` there is no reason to run your x-loop all the way to limit. The following should be faster although it is still `O(n^2)` so it will properly still take many years to get the solution for `L=10^12`

```
    $limit = 15;
    $result = array();
    $count = 0;        
    for ( $y=2; $y<=$limit; $y++ ) {
      for ( $x=1; $x<$y; $x++ ) {
        $n = ($x*$y)/($x+$y);

        if ( is_int( $n ) ) {
          $count++;
          $result[$count]['x'] = $x;
          $result[$count]['y'] = $y;
          $result[$count]['n'] = $n;
        }
      }
    }
    echo count( $result );
```

Comment: Won't it be slower assigning the value to `$n` and only then checking it, then checking the process itself?

Comment: I do not think so. Storing the expression takes almost no time. On top of that if you enter the if-statement you need the the value and it is definitely not smart to calculate it again. If you do not need it in side i guess it could be a tiny bit faster to not store it - but i do not think it is a noticeable difference.
Also i very much doubt you will be able to solve this by brute force. So as you suggest yourself - I think you need to think of a better algorithm :)

Comment: Oh, I solved it already, this was just to understand, how the numbers are formed :)